# How to use poll and push correctly Vaadin?

Tags: data-binding, websocket, vaadin, vaadin8

I have an application in Vaadin 8. The server changes its data randomly. The Labels what show the data are bindet. If i set the "setPollIntervall" works great but just not accurate to the second. Now I want to have it so that the label updates directly if something changes. Vaadin offers push, but how do I use both together?

Comment: Which Vaadin version are you using?

Comment: I am using Vaadin 8 in Eclipse

Comment: Usually you just set the @Push annotation and the server side changes are pushed to the client directly. No need for the `setPollintervall` in that case any longer. Just make sure to use the `access()`method to sync UI object access correctly.

Comment: @AndréSchild But i will use it with the Binder. And where i do readBean? So that my datas updating.

Comment: How does you vaadin app knows when new data is available?

Comment: I get datas from a REST Api

Comment: Have you looked at the docs? https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html